# Finding the Smallest Non-Negative Integer Not in a Given List

Tags: excel

I am attempting to write a program in Excel that finds the smallest non-negative integer not in a given list and places it into a cell. The list will contain only non-negative integers. I can do this if the values in the list have an upper bound quite easily using a series of if statements, but the list can (and will) contain arbitrarily large values. I am quite new to using Excel, so I would greatly appreciate it if you could provide a formula I could simply place into the cell (i.e. no macros, if possible). Thank you in advance for any assistance you can provide on this topic.

**Examples:**

- List = {0,1,2,3,4}, Output = 5
- List = {0,1,2,4,7}, Output = 3
- List = {1,2,3,4,7}, Output = 0

Comment: Could you give an example input and output you want? According to your description, I could just answer "-100000". Right?

Comment: What you are asking?It is little unclear to me

Comment: I apologize for the confusion; I didn't realize that I forgot to specify that the list values and output could not be negative. I edited the question to reflect this correction. Let me know if there is anything else I should clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your edited question then assuming you will have at least one integer missing in the range 0 to 99 try this formula where List is in `A1:A5`

`=SMALL(IF(COUNTIF(A1:A5,ROW(INDIRECT("1:100"))-1)=0,ROW(INDIRECT("1:100"))-1),1)`

confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

This version will also give you the same result without "array entry"

`=LOOKUP(2,1/(COUNTIF(A1:A5,100-ROW(INDIRECT("1:100")))=0),100-ROW(INDIRECT("1:100")))`

See example below showing the outcome for each of your example lists:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

`MIN(A:A)` will get you the smallest number in column A - just subtract 1 (or any number really) to get a number smaller than any of those (or use `MAX` to get largest). Update the formula as necessary based on where your data is. If the result needs to be an integer, just `ROUNDDOWN` it.

Comment: Fixed to be specific to integer values.